# Basic tests to create a new REST API with sprint boot that reads data from an existing spanner database

Tags: database, spring-boot, rest, google-cloud-spanner

I have been tasked with creating a new REST API with Spring Boot that connects to a GCP Spanner database that has already been created.

Can someone please help me understand the initial steps that need to be taken to create the API and connect to the database?

Once connected I feel comfortable to be able to query the database but not sure how to get the connection up and running.

Comment: You should try to make this question more pointed. This is a very generic 'give me a tutorial of...' type of question, and not pointed specifically at something like 'I already have XYZ running, but I don't know how to make a connection to Cloud Spanner. I've already tried 1, 2, and 3'.

Comment: There is a generic sample for using Cloud Spanner with Spring Data JPA (Hibernate) and that exposes a REST API here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate/tree/master/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate-samples/spring-data-jpa-sample

That might be able to get you started.